# check whether matrix has rational or irrational eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let {${v_1,v_2,....v_{16}}$} be the ordered basis for $V=\mathbb{C^{16}}$.If $T$ is a linear transformation on $V$ defined by.
$T(v_i)=v_{i+1}$ for $1\leq i\leq 15$ and $T(v_{16})=-(v_1+v_2+.....+v_{16})$  .so the question is.

> Is $T$  invertible? and also check whether $T$ has  rational eigenvalues.

Solution I tried: first we make a matrix which represents the given transformation.

\begin{pmatrix}
 0& 1 &  0&0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  1& 0 &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0& 1 &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&0  &1  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  1&  0&  0& 0 & 0 &  0&0  &0  &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&0  &0  &1  &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0& 0 & 0 & 1 &  0&  0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0&  0& 0 & 0 &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1&  0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0&  0&0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&0  &0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  0& 0 &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &1  &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&0  &0  &0  &0  &  0&0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &1  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
 0&   0&   0&    0&   0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0&  0&  0&  0&0  &1 \\ 
 -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1&  -1& -1
\end{pmatrix}

as we can see from the given matrix that rank of matrix is 16, so the matrix is invertible ,but I stuck on the part in which we have to check whether that matrix hase  rational or irrational eigenvalues.

Please help

Thank you.

Comment: I think that's the "companion matrix" to a very simple polynomial.

Comment: Thank you ,now i got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v = a_1v_1+...+a_{15}v_{15}+a_{16}v_{16}$ be in $Ker (T)$

Then $T(v)=0$ so $$a_1v_2+a_2v_3+...+a_{15}v_{16}-a_{16}(v_1+...+v_{16})=0$$

so $$ -a_{16}v_1+(a_1-a_{16})v_2+...+(a_{15}-a_{16})v_{16}=0$$

so $a_{16}=0$ and $a_i-a_{16}=0$ for all $i\leq 15$ so $v=0$ and thus the kernel is trivial and so $T$ is invertibile.

---

If that is correct what you say about a characteristic equation then it has no real egienvalues, since it can be written as $${x^{17}-1\over x-1}=0\implies x^{17}=1$$

so the only real solution to this equation is $x=1$ (since the map $x\mapsto x^{17}$ is strictly increasing) but this is not a solution to that characteristic polynomial of degree $16$.

Comment: the characteristic equation of this matrix is $x^{16}+x^{15}+x^{14}+......+1$